# Load sidebar.php based on window size using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to load my sidebar (sidebar.php) based on window size. The original code loaded the sidebar regardless of the window size. It works fine, but I need to change it so that it only loads the sidebar if the window is greater than a specific width. This was the original:

```
<?php include("sidebar.php"); ?>
```

I'm trying to use jQuery to accomplish loading ONLY if the window is big enough to show it. The #sidebarcontainer is the main div where all of the sidebar content goes. Here is what I have tried:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if($(window).width() > 665){
$("#sidebarcontainer").load("sidebar.php");
}
});
</script>
```

This isn't working. The sidebar does not show at all on any size window.

And I think I need an else statement in there as well that says do not load if if it isn't greater than 665?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code **100% working** and tested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Load demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<b>Response:</b>
<div id="sidebarcontainer"></div>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
  if($(window).width() > 665){
    $( "#sidebarcontainer" ).load( "register.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
      if ( status == "success" ) {
        $('#sidebarcontainer').show();
      }
      if ( status == "error" ) {
        //var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        //$( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
        $('#sidebarcontainer').hide();
      }
    });
 }
 else{
   $('#sidebarcontainer').remove();
 }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks..what would go into the "do stuff" section if I only want the page to load if window width is greater than 665?

Comment: also, can I just load the sidebar.php file without designating the #sidebarcontainer as the place for it to load?

Comment: Not working for me. The sidebar does not show up on any window size. FYI: the sidebar.php file is originally called in the index page and the #sidebarcontainer is in the sidebar.php file.

Comment: That is your problem.  You are trying to load something into #sidebarcontainer but #sidebarcontainer doesn't exist until you load sidebar.php.  You need to have this element present first.

Comment: Are you sure `<div id="sidebarcontainer"></div>` container exist in `index.php`

Comment: Ahhh...I see. Shoot. I need to think about how to do this.

Comment: You need to define sidebar are for using this, without you can't load file on exact location..

Comment: No, #sidebarcontainer does NOT exist in index.php...it exists only on the sidebar.php file.

Comment: You can set <div id="sidebarcontainer" style="display:none;"></div>

Comment: Let me try to add: <div id="sidebarcontainer" style="display:none;"></div> to the index.php ...

Comment: After loaded file you can show `#sidebarcontainer` to add using this code :   `$('#sidebarcontainer').show();`

Comment: Don't forgot to remove `#sidebarcontainer` from `register.php` after add in `index.php` file

Comment: also, I don't want an error div--just show sidebar.php if window is greater than 665 else do not show.

Comment: took a bit of finessing as a lot of javascript on the site but it seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: I tried to up vote but says I am too new to the forum...also, I'm perplexed in developer tools chrome shows not working in quirktools/screenfly shows working. I need to test on an actual device...have it set to greater than 768 at the moment.

Comment: OK...so it appears that it is not solved, but I was able to create media queries to hide the sidebarcontainer at different window widths. Thanks for the help though.